# r, shiny, ggplot2 -- resize bar chart according to number of records

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

My shiny app displays a chart that has differing numbers of rows, from half a dozen to many dozens. I have not been able to dynamically resize the chart according to the number of rows, as I could if it were a PDF or PNG.
======================ui.R==========================
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

```
shinyUI
(
  fluidPage
  (
    titlePanel("University Enrollment Application"),
    sidebarLayout
    (
      position = "right",
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("param", label = "From the following list, select the category by which to see the enrollment count.", choices =  c("Faculty Ranks" = "FacRankDesc", "Section Locations" = "Sections", "Enrollments per Term" = "Term", "Academic Level" = "SecLev", "Grade Distribution" = "Grade", "Enrollments per College" = "Colleges", "Student Locations" = "Students", "Student Programs" = "Programs", "Enrollments by Subject" = "Subj"), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
        ),
        mainPanel
        (
            h3("Instructions"),
            p("This application displays the count of enrollments for the 2013-2014 Academic Year by the designated categories. To display the enrollment counts, please choose a category from the select box at the right. The options are listed below."), 
            p("Faculty Rank, enrollments by faculty rank", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            p("Section Locations, enrollments by the location of the course section", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            p("Term, enrollments by semester or term", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            p("Grades, enrollments by final grade", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            p("Student Locations, enrollments by the current home location of the student", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            p("Programs, enrollments by academic program (the display does not adjuct", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            p("Subject, enrollments by the department of the course section", style = 'font-size: 10pt'),
            h3(textOutput("param")),
            h3(textOutput("h")),
            plotOutput("hist")
            #h1(grepl(":upper", textOutput("param"), perl = TRUE))
            #if (textOutput("param") == grepl("\\w", textOutput("param"), perl = TRUE)) { h1(textOutput("param")) }
          #plotOutput("distPlot")
      )#mainPanel


    )#sidebarLayout
  )#fluidPage
)#shinyUI
```

======================server.R==========================
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

```
df <- read.csv("data/df.csv")

shinyServer
(
  function(input, output) 
  {
    output$param <- renderText({paste("You have selected ", input$param)})
    h <- renderTable({df[,input$param]})
    output$hist <- renderPlot(
      {ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,input$param]), environment = environment()) +
      #{ggplot(df, aes(x = FacRankDesc), environment = environment()) +
          geom_histogram() +
          theme_bw() +
          ggtitle(paste0("Count of ", input$param)) +
          ylab(paste0("Number of Enrollments by ", input$param)) +
          xlab(input$param) +
          theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
          coord_flip() 
},
height = 800
)
}
)
```

===================end of code=====================

Result is something like this:

http://spectrum.troy.edu/cccarter/shinyimage.png

If I were printing to a PNG or PDF, I can do something like this:

```
    chart.height <- length(unique(data.frame$X))
... in PNG or PDF ...
    width <- chart.height
... flip X and Y ...
```

How can I resize the bar chart according to the number or unique records using ggplot2 in shiny?

Thanks, CC.

Comment: Can you make your question self contained? Shiny app and code can go offline without notice, making this question less useful for future generations.